# Find if the metric space $\mathbb R$ with $d(x,y) = |e^x - e^y|$ is complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Consider the metric space $(\mathbb R,d)$, where $d(x,y) = |e^x −e^y|$, $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$. Is the metric space $(\mathbb R,d)$ complete?

I understand the definition of completeness but am unable to prove this?

Can you provide me with a counterexample, I understand it is not complete.

Comment: You understand it is not complete? Could you elaborate please? If you do understand it, then what is your question? It would be easier to answer your question if you provide details clarifying which part exactly you do understand, and which part you do not understand. (In particular, after you put a comment on a posted correct answer, you requesting an elaboration how that answer related to the definition of completeness.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sequence $x_n = -n$. Compute that
$$\lim_{n,m \rightarrow \infty} |e^{x_n} - e^{x_m}| = \lim_{n,m \rightarrow \infty}|e^{-n} - e^{-m}| \leq \lim_{n,m \rightarrow \infty} e^{-n} + e^{-m} = 0,$$
So $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. But $(x_n)$ is not convergent. To see this, suppose toward a contradiction that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |e^x - e^{-n}| = 0$. But then it follows that $e^x = 0$, which is absurd.

Comment: Please elaborate relating to the definition of completeness

Comment: @Didi The definition of completeness is "Every Cauchy sequence is convergent", which is precisely what is refuted in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

User Levi has answered this question.

A bit formal:

1) $x_n =\log n$ is Cauchy.

Let $m \ge n$.

$|e^{-\log m} -e^{-\log n}|=|1/m-1/n| <1/m+1/n \le 2/n;$

$\epsilon >0$;

Let $n_0>2/\epsilon.$

For $m \ge n \ge n_0 $ we have

$|e^{x_m}-e^{x_n}| < 2/n \le 2/n_0 <\epsilon$.

2) Assume $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is the limit.

For $\epsilon >0$

there is a $n_1$ s.t. for $n \ge n_1$

$|e^{-x}-1/n| < \epsilon.$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|e^{-x}-1/n| =e^{-x} \lt \epsilon$;

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary it follows $e^{-x} = 0,$ a contradiction.